# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "Could not parse auth token." to type 'valuesClass' in using FireBase and WinForms

Tags: python, c#, firebase, winforms

I'm trying to pass data from a **Raspberry Pi** device to a **firebase** database. I've been successful on making the Pi side of things workout. But so far I've been unsuccessful on making the data flow to my pc **using WinForms and C#.**

The expected result would be the data inside the database flow to the GUI in WinForms.

Firebase profile has a parent and that parent has 2 children. The parent is named `values` and the two children named `gyroData` and `sarjData`. One equal to `"10"` and the other equal to `"5"`. I have had a suspicion that the string values could be the issue but it was not. ***I've tried changing them to integer values which resulted in another error.***

Here is my C# program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using FireSharp;
using FireSharp.Config;
using FireSharp.Response;
using FireSharp.Interfaces;

namespace databaseGUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        IFirebaseConfig config = new FirebaseConfig
        {
            // double checked these in my program, all proper.
            BasePath = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            AuthSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        };
        
        IFirebaseClient client;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);
            if (client != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connected");
            }
        }

        private void RTBButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FirebaseResponse response = client.Get(@"values");
            Dictionary<string, valuesClass> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, valuesClass>>(response.Body.ToString());
            PopulateRTB(data);
        }

        private void dataView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FirebaseResponse response = client.Get(@"values");
            Dictionary<string, valuesClass> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, valuesClass>>(response.Body.ToString());
            PopulateDataView(data);
        }

        private void PopulateRTB(Dictionary<string, valuesClass> record)
        {
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            foreach (var item in record)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += item.Key + "\n";
                richTextBox1.Text += item.Value.gyroData + "\n";
                richTextBox1.Text += item.Value.sarjData + "\n";
            }
        }

        private void PopulateDataView(Dictionary<string, valuesClass> record)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("gyrodata", "Gyro");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("sarjdata", "Sarj");

            foreach (var item in record)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item.Key, item.Value.gyroData, item.Value.sarjData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My data class:

```
namespace databaseGUI
{
    class degerlerClass
    {
        public string gyroData { get; set; }
        public string sarjData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my python program:

```
import smbus
import time
from pyrebase import pyrebase
import sys

config = {
    "apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "authDomain": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com",
    "databaseURL": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    "storageBucket":"" 
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

data = {"sarj": str(10), "gyro": str(5) }
db.child("values").set(data)

print(data)
```

Comment: @IVSoftware the value of ```response.Body.ToString()``` is equal to, ```{ "error" : "Could not parse auth token." }```

Comment: Clearly something is not right with my initiation, right? I wouldn't have guessed so. I'll try and test your mock client.